# slideshare in android app

Tags: android, embed, android-webview, slideshow

I am new to Android and I am studying the possibility of including/embedding a slideshare slideshow (among other contents) into an Android app.

The idea would be receiving from the user the URL of the resource, such as:

"http://es.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/16060200?rel=0"

And in certain section of the app display the slideshow mixed with other contents (text or whatever...)

I have been searching and the only option I saw (I insist I am really new to this...) would be making a webview for that activity... but... Is a webview fullscreen only? Can it be just part of an activty?

I hope I got to make myself understood... otherwise, let's try to clear it out and ask me whatever you may need to understand the question ;)

Thank you very much in advance,

Miguel

PS: I can accept other systems instead of slideshare, what i want is to embed an slideshow

Comment: Whoa, thank you... I never got to see this answer. Thank you very much. I got to solve the Issue... just so ppl know, I get the embed code from the oembed API of slideshare and the embed it in a webview of the size I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is a `WebView`, just like you said. They can be non-fullscreen as well. Not sure how much this helps, but here's a tutorial on WebView's from the dev site:

[Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: tack så mycket Keyser! det var bra ^__^ det hjälpte mig